# I am using deeplearning4j library. Anybody knows how to feed the bag of words to feed forward neural network?

Tags: java, neural-network

I am using a deeplearning4j library. Anybody knows how to feed the bag of words to feed forward neural network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

```
        MultiLayerNetwork model = new MultiLayerNetwork(conf);model.init();model.setListeners(new ScoreIterationListener(100)); for(int i = 0; i < nEpochs; i++) { model.fit(bow.vectorize(new File("Pass here single file"), "label name"));
   }
```